# How Do I Insert a Variable into a PHP 'Include'?

Tags: php, url, variables, syntax, include

Not much to explain really, I just cant figure out the correct syntax to use a variable in an include URL

heres what I thought it would be:

```
$round_num=1;
include '../../fixtures/round{$round_num}fix.php';
```

It returns the usual:

```
Warning: include(../../fixtures/round{$round_num}fix.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

This must be a very simple one for allot of you out there lol but i just cant find my answer ANYWHERE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotes (`"`) to delimit your string. String interpolation doesn't occur in single quoted (`'`) strings.

```
$round_num=1;
include "../../fixtures/round{$round_num}fix.php";
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
so i have to use double quotes whenever i want to use a variable in something like this?

Comment: @ProdigyDoo Or concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use alternate syntax such as:

```
include "../../fixtures/round" . $round_num . "fix.php";
```

Sometimes people prefer to have the variable highlighted by their IDE for clarity.

Comment: Personally I don't see the point of using double quotes _and_ escaping the variable.

Comment: I usually don't do this;however, it's very common.